# Sql Find Changing Data Sets

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a database where people are inserted monthly:

**Person** *{PersonId, Date}*

where the date is just the month the person is captured in and the ideal case is each person is captured every month. However this does no happen. I want to be able to see which people are missing from the different months.

Moreover if a person starts being captured from month x I dont want to see him as being missing from month x-y. So for example if a person starts getting captured from March, he cannot be missing from jan or feb, but can be missing in following months.

How Could this be achieved in SQL.

**Edit:**

```
PERSON DATE

Jon   2014-01-01
Jon   2014-03-01

Mike  2014-02-01
Mike  2014-03-01

Sam   2014-01-01
Sam   2014-02-01
Sam   2014-03-01
```

So the answer would be something like:

```
2014-01-01 no one missing (Mike isn't missing as capturing him only started in feb)
2014-02-01 Jon missing
2014-03-01 No one missing
```

Comment: Which database system?

Comment: edit the question to include some sample data and the expected query result

Comment: This question would be easier to answer if you'd include some sample data, DB structure and expected result format.

Comment: I Hope that helps? Also database is MSSQL

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?  Later ones have handy features that help out.  In the case of multiple people missing for the same entry, do you want multiple rows or an aggregated column (if possible)?  Why are you capturing data every month anyways?

Comment: The source provides the data monthly, thus we capture it as soon as we can. We are using SQL Server 2012